# Having issue with draw timing diagram for logic circuit

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

[image]

This is a question for draw a timing diagram for the circuit I was try to do, but I don't understand what is the first input I should use then go through the whole circuit.

Can anyone explain to me step by step?  By the way, I know the basic things about timing diagram and flip flop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'll do the first step for you.  You should be able to do the rest.  Just before the first negative edge after the reset [q2,q1,q0] = 000.  This means [j2,j1,j0] = 001.  So after the edge [q2,q1,q0] = 001.  Notice that j0 and k0 are tied together.  This makes it work like a T.  That means if inputs are one the flip-flop changes to the opposite state.  If they are 0 nothing happens.  The same is true of j1, k1.  The last flip-flop is the only one actually set up as a JK.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when doing this you start from the left, identify unique nets (Signals) and work your way right.

In this instance they made it easy for you since A,B and C as defined, though you may want to name and plot the output of than AND gate and also show \$\overline C\$ for completeness.

\$\overline C\$ is actually your first unique net anyway.

Comment: which means because the reset is 0 and and I put 0 into the last flip flop so c become 1?

Comment: @ZhuangzhuangLi yes, then carry on for all the other lines down that clock edge.